# "Cannot call delete() after .distinct()" error after django update

Tags: django

I am using djangocms_blog.
Today I updated django from 3.1 to 3.2.12 and suddenly when I try to delete post object, there is "Cannot call delete() after .distinct()" error
Traceback:

```
env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py, line 47, in inner
                response = get_response(request) …
env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 181, in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py, line 616, in wrapper
                return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs) …
env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py, line 130, in _wrapped_view
                    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) …
env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py, line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
        response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) …
env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py, line 232, in inner
            return view(request, *args, **kwargs) …
env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py, line 43, in _wrapper
        return bound_method(*args, **kwargs) …
env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py, line 130, in _wrapped_view
                    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) …
env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py, line 1739, in changelist_view
                response = self.response_action(request, queryset=cl.get_queryset(request)) …
env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py, line 1408, in response_action
            response = func(self, request, queryset) …
env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\actions.py, line 45, in delete_selected
            modeladmin.delete_queryset(request, queryset) …
env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py, line 1109, in delete_queryset
        queryset.delete() …
env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py, line 728, in delete
            raise TypeError('Cannot call delete() after .distinct().') …
```

I restored Django 3.1 version and everything works fine, but working on old version isn't best solution

Comment: Where does the `.distinct()` originates from? Normally querysets in the `ModelAdmin` do not have a `.distinct()`.

Comment: This link can be helpful https://fixexception.com/django/cannot-call-delete-after-distinct/

Comment: I found this article earlier.
@WillemVanOnsem very good question.

Comment: As you can see in traceback there are only functions from django app
In none of them have I found distinct()

Comment: This is a bug in `djangocms-blog` - see https://github.com/nephila/djangocms-blog/issues/683 . There are a couple of monkey-patches described in that issue for getting around it. but ultimately this has to be fixed in that package.

Comment: That's it, thank you so much. I think I will update django to 3.2 version when django-cms bug-fix will be available

Answer (score 0):

Fixed via setting

```
Django = ">=3.2,<3.3"
```

in pyproject.toml, so it selected itself Django 3.2.13.

Answer (score 0):

We were using a list filter in one of our admin classes, that was internally overriding `get_queryset` and that always returned a `distinct()`. Improving that filter method eliminated this bug.